# How to write endpoint information in app.config at runtime WCF?

Tags: wcf

Is there a way to write in a app.config file the information about endpoints?
Actually I want to read the `<service>` tag from one app.config file and want to write it in other app.config file's `<Services>`  tag.

Please anyone tell me how can I do it?

Actually I have a config file called "WCFService.exe.config" which i want to read in my program , so what i am writing is:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "WCFService.exe.config");
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path)  

ServicesSection serviceSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/services") as ServicesSection;

ServiceElementCollection sereleColl = serviceSection.Services;
```

but i get nothing in sereleColl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [ConfigurationManager class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager_members.aspx)

I don't remember how to do it though.

**Edit:**

To access it you have to add a reference to System.Configuration.

**Edit 2:**

Changing the appsettings can be done like this:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
AppSettingsSection appSettings = config.AppSettings;
KeyValueConfigurationElement setting = appSettings.Settings["MyAppSettingsKey"];
setting.Value = "newValue";
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

You can access the WCF settings by typing:

```
ConfigurationSectionGroup sct = config.SectionGroups["system.serviceModel"];
```

Hope this helps.

**Comment:**

Your code is working fine here. However, I changed

```
string path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "WCFService.exe.config");
```

to

```
string path = Application.ExecutablePath;
```

This will use the config file of the application currently running. I don't know why your path doesn't work. Either it's that, or there must be an error in your config file?

Comment: actually i don't want to read the app.config of current executable but I want to read another app.config file which is "WCFService.exe.config".

Comment: I am still able to load other configs using your method.

Comment: My only thought is that there must be something wrong in your config file, but I guess you have reviewed it :-)

Comment: marc_s is correct, even though we specify a path, it is the executables config that is loaded.

Comment: you mean i can read any config file , i just need to give the correct path.

Comment: I'm not sure how it works, but you should read the articles posted by marc_s.

Answer (score 3):

Your calling "OpenExeConfiguration" - this will open the config for the currently executing app.

You need to read up on the .NET 2.0 configuration system: there's an excellent 3-part series on the .NET configuration system on CodeProject:

There's a series of really good articles on you to demystify the .NET 2.0 configuration system on CodeProject:

1. [Unraveling the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx)
2. [Decoding the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration2.aspx)
3. [Cracking the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx)

Highly recommended! Jon Rista did a great job explaining the configuration system in .NET 2.0.